# Getting an Array inside a Rails object generated by a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rest

I need to generate a JSON from a `form_tag`. The structure I'm trying to generate is something like this:

```
"recipients": [
    {
        "account": {
            "accountId": "4",
            "account": "4",
            "branch": "4"
        },
        "order": {
            "orderId": "4",
            "dateTime": "4",
            "description": "4"
        },
        "amount": "3",
        "mediatorFee": "0",
        "currency": "0"
    },
    {
        "account": {
            "accountId": "4",
            "account": "4",
            "branch": "4"
        },
        "order": {
            "orderId": "4",
            "dateTime": "4",
            "description": "4"
        },
        "amount": "3",
        "mediatorFee": "0",
        "currency": "0"
    }
]
```

I'm doing it like this:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Recipients</legend>
  <p>Account</p>
  <div>
    <%= label_tag 'AccountId' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'recipients[][account][accountId]', nil , class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= label_tag 'Account' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'recipients[][account][account]', nil , class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= label_tag 'Branch' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'recipients[][account][branch]', nil , class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <p>Order</p>
  <div>
    <%= label_tag 'OrderId' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'recipients[][order][orderId]', nil , class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= label_tag 'DateTime' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'recipients[][order][dateTime]', nil , class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= label_tag 'Description' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'recipients[][order][description]', nil , class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <p>Recipients</p>
  <div>
    <%= label_tag 'Amount' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'recipients[][amount]', (params['recipients[][amount]'] or 0) , class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= label_tag 'Mediator Fee' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'recipients[][mediatorFee]', (params['recipients[][mediatorFee]'] or 0) , class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= label_tag 'Currency' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'recipients[][currency]', (params['recipients[][currency]'] or 0) , class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

My controller is:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'
require 'json'
require 'digest'


class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
 def index
end

  def sendPayment
   params.delete :utf8
   params.delete :commit
   params.delete :controller
   params.delete :action

@jsonParams = params
puts @jsonParams.to_json
@result = HTTParty.post('http://url.url.com'.to_str,
:body => @jsonParams.to_json,
:headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
              'Api-Access-Key' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
              'Transaction-Hash' => 'dsa' } )

 puts @result
#  redirect_to root_path
end

end
```

I need to add more objects inside this array. How can I do that?

Comment: Please, provide models and controller which renders this view.

Comment: The only thing I do have is a Controller to get the information from the form and send it to the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For browsers to understand - you only have to duplicate your fields, since you already have array mark in field names, but there seems to be a bug in rack query parser that makes it drop some data on deep nesting:

```
q = Rack::Utils.build_nested_query(
   {a:[{b:{c:"this will be lost"}}, {b:{c:2}}]}
) #=> "a[][b][c]=this+will+be+lost&a[][b][c]=2"

Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(q) # => {"a"=>[{"b"=>{"c"=>"2"}}]}
```

While without deep nesting it works:

```
Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(Rack::Utils.build_nested_query({a:[{b:"will not be lost"}, {b:2}]})) #=> {"a"=>[{"b"=>"will not be lost"}, {"b"=>"2"}]}
```

So as a workaround you can name fields `recipients[0][account][accountId]`, `recipients[1][account][accountId]` and so on and then recombine the array:

```
params["recipients"] = params["recipients"].values if params["recipients"].is_a?(Hash)
```

Comment: Worked just fine! Thank you :)